# Avoid repetitive adding and removing of classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

have a javascript code below:

```
   myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      current_candy++;
      let previous_step = current_step - 1;
      if(( current_candy > 0) && (current_candy <= stepCount)){
        previous.classList.remove("d-none");
        previous.classList.add("d-inline-block");
        step[current_candy].classList.remove("d-none");
        step[current_candy].classList.add("d-block");
        step[current_candy].classList.remove("d-block");
        step[previous_step].classList.add("d-none");
        if (current_candy == stepCount){
          submit.classList.remove("d-none");
          submit.classList.add("d-inline-block");
          next.classList.remove("d-inline-block");
          next.classList.add("d-none");
        }
      } else {
        if(current_candy > stepCount){
            form.onsubmit = () => { return true }
        }
      }
    });
```

As you can see that I am constantly adding and removing classes from this program.

Is there better way to do this? Is this a good practice?

Comment: What's the relationship between `current_step` and `current_candy`? And could you tell us in words what the code is *meant* to do?

Comment: Well…if you’re using class name to keep track of some kind of “state”, you need sth to save that state anyway. I don’t know what purpose your class name serves, all I can say is, this is normal practice.

Comment: It might help to know that `classList.toggle` is a method. Also that `classList.add` and `classList.remove` can take multiple arguments. I can't see the point in adding and then removing the "d-block" class from the same object (unless one of your `current_candy` variables should be `previous_step`). But more importantly it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve overall. It's certainly fine to add/remove classes on click events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toggle instead of add/remove classes, it returns true if the class was added, and false if it was removed.

for example:

```
submit.classList.toggle('d-block');
```

Check out w3schools example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class